# Spring Boot JPA Pagination Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am implementing pagination for my service where limit and offset comes as a part of request body. When I have set these values in the PageRequest at the Service level, I am getting the following error and the implementation

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.assertEitherAllParamAnnotatedOrNone(Parameters.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaParameters.<init>(JpaParameters.java:43) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.createParameters(JpaQueryMethod.java:325) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.createParameters(JpaQueryMethod.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Student Request:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "paging": {
    "limit": 0,
    "startOffset": 0
  }
}
```

Student Service:

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public List<Student> getAllStudents(StudentRequest studentRequest) {

       List<Student> studentList = studentRepository.getAll(studentRequest,new PageRequest(studentRequest.getPaging().getStartOffset(), studentRequest.getPaging().getLimit()));
       return studentList;
    }
}
```

Student Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select o from Student  o  where (o.name = :#{#studentRequest.name} OR :#{#studentRequest.name} IS NULL ) ")
    public List<Student> getAll(@Param("studentRequest") StudentRequest studentRequest, PageRequest pageRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error:

`use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!`

This means that you **cannot** use `@Param` in a `Pageable` (or `PageRequest`) and `Sort` parameters, they are handled automatically by spring.

Just remove the `@Param("pageRequest")` and it will work.

Tip: Use `Pageable` interface instead of `PageRequest` class.

Comment: How to handle in case if my request does not have limit and start offset values?

Comment: Default values Will be applied. 25 for limit and page 0.

Comment: Limit is actually handled as size property

Comment: @Devidi Cavarazan: I do not think it is taking the default values which is why it is throwing an exception. Should I pass the values 0 and 25 manually when creating PageRequest object?

Comment: Hum, using Pageable as a parameter it should apply it. How you build your URL to call this resource?

Comment: It will be a post request where these parameters are defined in the request body. I have posted the request in the question.

Comment: @user8363477 but the URl itself is: like :http://localhost:8080/api/xxx?page=0&size=25

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the assertion that's failing just wants you to either have `AllParamAnnotatedOrNone`. So you would do:

```
public List<Student> getAll(@Param("studentRequest") StudentRequest studentRequest, 
    @Param("pageRequest") PageRequest pageRequest);
```

Even though you're not using it; you just need one pattern (i.e. named Spring Data params) here or the other (i.e. inferred Spring Data param names).